# How to handlle alternateitem and selected item cssclasses in asp.net web form gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am working on a asp.net web form gridview. The rows have either "GridViewItem" or "GridViewAlternateItem" as the class to set the background color of the rows. Once a row is clicked the row will have those two CssClass replaced with "DataGridSelectedItem". All these three classes have unique colors. When the row is created I am updating the onmouseover and onmouseout attributes as follows.

```
 row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.className='" + RowHighlightStyle.CssClass + "';");
 row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.className='" + className + "';");
```

The problem is the color of the highlighted row having the class "DataGridSelectedItem" is changed to either "GridViewAlternateItem" or "GridViewItem" due to the onmouseover and onmouseout events. Instead I would like to keep the class of "DataGridSelectedItem" as such during mouseout.

I tried the following. But this simply replaces the background color of all the rows in mouseout.

```
e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "highlight(this, true);";
e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "highlight(this, false);";

<script type="text/javascript">

function highlight(tableRow, active) {
    if (active) {
        alert(tableRow.style.backgroundColor);
        tableRow.style.backgroundColor = '#cfc';
    }
    else {
        tableRow.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    }
}

function link(Url) {
    document.location.href = Url;
}
```

Comment: What is your goal? Highlighting the row under the mouse cursor?

Comment: Yes, during the mouseout, the original background color should remain.

Comment: Maybe if you can show (some of) your CSS, I can give a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to highlight the row under the mouse cursor, the I'd suggest a solution based on CSS, without any javascript.

E.g. define some CSS styles which are only active while the cursor is hovering over the grid rows:

CSS:

```
tr.GridViewItem:hover,
tr.GridViewAlternateItem:hover,
tr.DataGridSelectedItem:hover {
  background-color: #cfc;
}
```

Put these styles after your normal CSS styles (GridViewItem, GridViewAltenateItem and DataGridSelectedItem) and they will be applied to the row where the cursor is positioned (due to the `:hover` pseudo-class).

You can then remove any javascript code (e.g. `highlight()`) and the code-behind setting the row-attributes.

Comment: It sounds like a very good suggestion. However, the third CssClass, "DataGridSelectedItem" is used only by one gridview. The codebehind javascript setting the "onmouseover" and "onmouseout" are used by several other gridviews.So, I may not be able to remove that code.  Probably I could check whether the CssClass equals "DataGridSelectedItem" and then set the mouseout differently. But, I couldn't find a codebehind event which I could use. The codebehind event where the js is set is called before the "DataGridSelectedItem" cssclass is applied.

Comment: @Drifter: my point was this: you don't need any javascript or code-behind to highlight the row under the cursor. You only need some CSS.

Comment: This turned out to be a perfect solution for my issue. Thanks!